# SQL Server query for getting the Main Data and it sub Components in next next row

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table `ComponentMaster` with columns `ID`, `MainAssetID`, `SerialNo`.

`AssetID` is the primary key of the `AssetMaster` table and foreign key in `ComponentMaster`. In `AssetMaster` there are columns `AssetID`, `Serialno` etc

My requirement is I need the `MainAssetID` in first row and the sub components of that `MainAssetID` in next row.

`ComponentMaster`:

```
ID    MainAssetID     SerialNo
---------------------------------
1        24          4561334054   
2        24          4561334099   
3        24          4561334158
```

`AssetMaster`:

```
AssetID     SerialNo
----------------------------
24          YLCD002160
```

I need the output as

```
SerialNo
----------
YLCD002160
4561334054  
4561334099  
4561334158
```

Can anyone please guide me for doing this?

Comment: Why do you have `SerialNo` in both tables? That seems redundant ...

Comment: @marc-s: Actually this redundant occurred due to the continuous changes in the requirement and myself resolved the same. In future I will follow your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 Select SerialNo From (
 Select AssetId, SerialNo, 1 as n From AssetMaster
 Union all
 Select MainAssetId, SerialNo, 2 as n From ComponentMaster) a
 Order by  AssetId, n, SerialNo
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks much for your suggestion Giorgi Nakeuri. Your suggestion helped me a lot. I have resolved the same by using the below query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         AssetID, 'MAIN ASSET' as TYPE, serialno 
     FROM 
         VW_COMPONENETS --(THIS WILL HAVE THE MAIN ASSETID SERIALNO ALONE

     UNION ALL

     SELECT 
         C.RF_AssetID, 'COMPONENT' as TYPE, SERIALNO 
     FROM 
         dbo.COMPONENTMASTER C
     LEFT OUTER JOIN
         dbo.AssetMaster A ON C.RF_COMPONENT = A.RF_SerialNo) tbl  
 ORDER BY
     AssetID,TYPE DESC
```

Regards,

Svs Suresh